# silverlight with forms authentification - redirect to login.aspx

Tags: c#, silverlight-4.0, forms-authentication, iis-7.5

I've got a Silverlight Application which uses forms authentication. I tried to deploy and run it on my new Test-Server but its really weird. 
I activated anonymous and forms authentication.

When I run [serverip] I get redirected to Login.aspx (which doesn't exists) and I don't know why.

When I run [serverip]/Default.aspx I get a blank white page. Fiddler shows me, that the Default.aspx page gets loaded, but getting the embedded Silverlight xap File results in a redirect through to Login.aspx.

Does someone have any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I deployed the application via file system. Unfortunately the user "everyone" had no access to the ClientBin-folder. Giving "everyone" access to this folder solved my problem.